# difference between a getter method and a method which returns the state of an instance variable?

Tags: java, guava

I am reading through the Guava library, and I keep running into methods that look something like this:

```
@Override public int size() {
  return size;
}
```

What is the difference (strategically, conventionally, etc) between the above and the following?

```
@Override public int getSize() {
  return size;
}
```

Or is there no difference? Is it just shorthand?

Comment: Getters can be used by tools which are processing JavaBeans, for instance Expression Language (EL) in JSP.

Comment: You thus confirm my own assumption that the latter is more conventional. But what, if any, are the advantages of the former?

Comment: @pgblu Seems like more a preference thing, probably depends on the person writing the code. It could also differ if your company or organization has code style guide it may require the `get_` prefix

Comment: This is an interesting question. I note that when using the Builder pattern, the "get" prefix is dropped too. As the others say, it's Java Bean convention vs. lack of Java Bean convention, but to what end?

Comment: So is there another reason to prefer `size()` over `getSize()` other than that it saves some typing?

Comment: Well, only one of these actually satisfies the `Collection` contract...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One form isn't using [JavaBeans conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions).  Functionally speaking, systems that expect you to follow those conventions will not work or be very cumbersome to set up if you use non-conventional getters/setters for your beans, but if you're *not*, then there's no real difference.

Since Guava has a lot of collections, and the `Collection` interface actually defines [a `size()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size()), my gut tells me that Guava is more inclined to follow the `Collection` interface than JavaBeans conventions.

Answer (score 2):

- In terms of performance there is no difference.
- In terms of readability they are also similar but `getAttribute` says more about what this method *does* (`size` can imply that we need to do some additional calculations, getters in most cases simply returns value).
- But I suspect that main reason that people tend to name their methods as get/set... is to let their class become proper JavaBean which will be properly handled by tools which are using JavaBeans like [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html).

Anyway about your example. I suspect that since `List`s are not supposed to be treated as `JavaBean`s there is no requirement to return `size` with `getSize()` so simple `size()` is enough.